# ARel select rows by string length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Is there a way to select records by the size of a string field using ARel? For example if I have a bunch of users, can I select all user's whose first names are 3 or fewer characters? I can do something like the following with strings

```
User.where('LENGTH("users"."firstname") < 3')
```

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
User.where(User.arel_table[:firstname].length.lt(3)
```

Comment: it seems that no such code is implemented in arel for now, you can: 1. open issue in arel's github code to implement it; 2. Implement it by yourself, then just open pull request for the project on guthub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no.  That being said, the reason you try to use Arel functionality is to avoid database dependent SQL functionality (e.g. Postgres and Mysql have different date handling functions).  `LENGTH()`, on the other hand, is a standard SQL function, and you won't have problems with portability of that query.

tl;dr - Using custom SQL for everything is bad practice.  Using custom SQL strategically is totally fine.

Comment: My intent was to do it in ARel so I could also negate it for another scope and only have to write the logic once. I'm doing it with a string condition for now since it's readable and due to naming, someone editing the code should notice the opposite scope and change them both.

Answer (score 1):

AREL's value is not just for DB cross-compatibility. I had a similar use case where I had to create AREL nodes for custom algebra.

I believe this is what you were looking for:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :firstname

  AREL_SHORT_NAMES = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'LENGTH',
    [arel_table[:firstname]]
  ).lt(3)

  scope :short_named, where(AREL_SHORT_NAMES)
  scope :normal_named, where(AREL_SHORT_NAMES.not)

end
```

Comment: Thanks @Kyle! That's an interesting approach that I look forward to trying.